# Devise feature tests not redirecting to sign_in page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, capybara

I've noticed some strange behavior ONLY in feature tests when a user is not logged in and they aren't being redirected to the sign in page and I'm trying to understand why.  I’m using poltergeist as the javascript driver.

Here's a couple of examples:

```
# works as expected
it 'redirects to sign_in page when not logged in' do
  get :index, {}
  expect(response).to eq('/users/sign_in')
end

# does not redirect to '/users/sign_in'
it 'should redirect to the user sign in page' do
  visit '/'
  expect(page.current_path).to redirect_to('/users/sign_in')
end
```

Does anyone know why devise isn’t redirecting to the sign_in page in feature tests?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use redirect_to with Capybara -- Capybara doesn't provide data on whether the page is redirecting it just provides the url it's on as a string.  You probably want

```
expect(page).to have_current_path('/users/sign_in')
```

Note: a naive way to attempt to check the same thing would be to do `expect(page.current_path).to eq('/users/sign_in')` however that would check the current_path immediately, which will cause flaky tests when used with JS capable drivers since most actions in those drivers can occur asynchronously.  Using the `have_current_path` matcher adds in waiting/retrying behavior and is therefore the correct method to use.

Comment: I tried this: expect(page).to have_current_path('/user/sign_in', url: true) and it returned:  expected "http://www.example.com/" to equal "/user/sign_in"

Comment: @user1200990  Why would you pass `url:true` ? that tells it to compare to the full url -- you're only comparing to the path - you also want to check your test.log and see what responses are being sent

Comment: when I take that out, it still doesn't work and I get:  expected "/" to equal "/user/sign_in"

Comment: @user1200990  Which means that your controller isn't actually redirecting anywhere -- check you test.log to see what responses are being sent.

Comment: EXACTLY - that's my question.   This is 150% regular Devise behavior.  I can prove it works as expected in a regular controller test but it doesn't work in, basically the EXACT same feature test.  Why?

Comment: @user1200990 Now that your test is written correctly - look at your test.log and see what response is actually being sent.  If it is actually a redirect then assuming you're using the rack-test driver with Capybara did you configure it with `follow_redirects: false` for some reason?